# after typing gcsfuse gs://bucketname/* /home/admin/(directory in vm instance), it's showing successfully mounted. but when I am typing ls, it's 0

Tags: unix, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I also did 'df -h' to see if it's properly mounted or not and then it's showing it is:

gs://bucketname/*  1.0P     0  1.0P   0% /home/admin/(directory in vm instance)

But inside the directory in vm instance when I am typing ls -l , I am gettin total 0. What's the reason behind it?

Comment: We should assume the bucket has some files, right?

Comment: yes@FerreginaPelona

Comment: This is not [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) anyway. Please ask it as [su], [sf] or [devops.se].

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just make up arguments; see [`mounting.md`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md) for reference.

The command for static mounting is:

```
mkdir /path/to/mount/point
gcsfuse my-bucket /path/to/mount/point
```

or for dynamic mounting, with a bucket name:

```
mkdir /path/to/mount/point
gcsfuse /path/to/mount/point
```

To unmount:

```
fusermount -u /path/to/mount/point
```

Comment: I already did that, static mounting.... but when I am in the point directory and typing ls I am getting zero, but there should be files @martin

Comment: You've entered an incorrect bucket name, therefore it's probably no wonder. Please stop interpreting and see how it actually has to be written, in order to match the expected syntax.

Comment: And please refrain from asking the same question multiple times; I've seen that. The documentation provides clear examples - but the command which you use simply does not match them; there is no `gs://` and also no `/*`.